# VB Custom Control Unable to draw outside preset space, cannot draw

Tags: vb.net

Custom control unable to draw outside a preset space.

There is a small box which it is possible to draw in at the top left but it never changes position or size. This means if I set Location or Size to values outside of this box, the image gets clipped.

Control:

```
Public Class mySprite
    Inherits UserControl

    Dim _location As System.Drawing.Point
    Dim _size As System.Drawing.Size

    Dim image as System.Drawing.Image

    Public Sub New()
        _location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        _size = New System.Drawing.Size(1, 1)

        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("sprite.png")

        Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Overloads Property Location As System.Drawing.Point
        Get
            Return Location
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Drawing.Point)
            _location = value
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Overloads Property Size As System.Drawing.Size
        Get
            Return _size
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Drawing.Size)
            _size = value
            ImageBase = ScaleImage(_ImageBase, _size.Width, _size.Height)
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        'MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics = e.Graphics

        g.Clear(Color.Transparent)

        If Visible Then
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim pic As New transPicBox
pic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100)
pic.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
pic.Visible = True
Me.Controls.Add(pic)
```

If anyone can improve title, post or answer, please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting Location or Size, call `MyBase.Location = value` and `MyBase.Size = value` respectively. Eg.

```
    Overloads Property Size As System.Drawing.Size
        Get
            Return _size
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Drawing.Size)
            _size = value
            MyBase.Size = value
            ImageBase = ScaleImage(_ImageBase, _size.Width, _size.Height)
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
```